# Why won't div center w/ auto margins?

Tags: html, css

I'm at a complete loss here.  I've tried everything. Different displays, positions, floats... Nothing seems to work:

**Markup:**

```
<div id="today-leads" class="total-wrap">
    <h2>Leads</h2>

<div id="leads-wrap">
    <div id="leads-total" class="total">224</div>
    <div id="leads-ticker-wrap">    <i class="icon-caret-up"></i>

        <div id="leads-percentage-change" class="higher">56%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
#leads-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#leads-ticker-wrap{
    float:left;
}
#leads-total{
    float:left;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q4hE/)

Comment: If you're just centering text, add `text-align:center` to the parent element. If you want to center the actual element, make it `inline-block` too.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Which div?

`leads-wrap` won't centre because it is an `inline-block` not a `block`, so it is influenced by the `text-align` property of its containing block.

`leads-ticker-wrap` and `leads-total` won't centre because (a) they are floating left and (b) you haven't set auto margins on them.

Answer (score 0):

Auto left/right margins only work when the element in question has a known width. So add something like

```
#leads-wrap
{
    width: 65%;
}
```

Obviously you adjust the actual width to whatever you need.